# Adding ArcMap standard toolbar to the form in C# .NET WinForms project

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have Windows Forms project with ArcObjects framework.

I have already added axMapControl1 to the form.
[image]

The question is How can I add a standard toolbar to the form and link it with axMapControl1 ?

Like this:

[image]

Is there any standard toolbar control in the ArcObjects or should make it by myself?

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial [Building a map viewing application using the ArcGIS Engine controls](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000243000000)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the ArcGIS Engine Controls to your Visual Studio toolbox.

You can do this by:

1. On the Toolbox, click ArcGIS Windows Forms. The ArcGIS Engine controls appear. If there is no ArcGIS Windows Forms, right-click the Toolbox, then click Choose Items.
2. On the Choose Toolbox Items dialog box, click the .NET Framework Components tab and select AxLicenseControl, AxMapControl, AxPageLayoutControl, AxTOCControl, and AxToolbarControl, then click OK. The controls appear in the Toolbox. See the following screen shot:

   [image]

*Note: Steps 1 and 2 above are taken directly from the following tutorial.*  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000243000000 *(See steps 3 and 4.)*

From there, it is simply a matter of drag n' drop.  The standard toolbar you're looking for is 'ToolbarControl' as listed in the above image.  You will have to reference some libraries and associate the controls with eachother, but the following tutorial will help you there.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000243000000

Answer (score 1):

Since this map command already exist you can just use the UID value and open the toolbar, see example code below:

```
ICommandBar pCmdBar; 

//Create two new UID objects from UID class

UID pUID = new UID();

UID pCommandUID=new UID(); 

//pUID value is ArcMap Standard ToolBar UID Value  taken from here

pUID.Value = “{5DEB1DB8-C2A9-11D1-B9A2-080009EE4E51}”; 

pCmdBar= ICommandBar)m_application.Document.CommandBars.Find(pUID, false, false);
```